# UndefinedTable: relation "user" does not exist

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I am deploying a fresh new Django app on the server. The problem is when I migrate all the apps in the project. I'm getting UndefinedTable: **relation "user" does not exist**.

Things I have done already:

- removed all the migrations from all the apps
- created a new database and new migrations and still getting that error.

Weird scenarios:

- After deployment when I run the Django app locally on the server and hit API locally on the server using **curl** everything is working fine. like user sign up, but when I try to see in the database it is just empty (refer to the screenshot below). it doesn't even show columns for this user table, but for other tables, I can see columns as well. [image]
- but if I hit API with server endpoint I'm getting 500 error with exception :

  **relation "user" does not exist
  LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "user" WHERE "user"."email" = '**
- after migrations I am able to create super user but when I tried to login getting 500 error. and Undefined table relation user does not exit.
  Expection:

[image: Exception]

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'registration.User'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
import uuid

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.utils import timezone

from .managers import CustomUserManager

from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

AUTH_PROVIDERS = {'facebook': 'facebook', 'google': 'google',
                  'twitter': 'twitter', 'email': 'email'}
# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # These fields tie to the roles!
    A = 1
    I = 2
    C = 3

    USER_ROLE = (
        (A, 'A'),
        (I, 'I'),
        (C, 'C')
    )

    # Roles created here
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_ROLE, blank=True, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    auth_provider = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=False,
        null=False, default=AUTH_PROVIDERS.get('email'))
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'role']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_staff = True if self.role == self.ADMIN else False
        self.is_superuser = True if self.role == self.ADMIN else False
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def tokens(self):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token)
        }
```

managers.py (CustomUserManager)

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model where the email address is the unique identifier
    and has an is_admin field to allow access to the admin app
    """

    def create_user(self, username, email, role, password=None):
        if username is None:
            raise TypeError('Users should have a username')
        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Users should have a Email')

        user = self.model(username=username, role=role, email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, role, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        if password is None:
            raise TypeError('Password should not be none')
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            email,
            role,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

views.py

```
    renderer_classes = (UserRenderer,)
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        user_data = serializer.data
        user = User.objects.get(email=user_data['email'])
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user).access_token
        current_site = get_current_site(request).domain
        relativeLink = reverse('email-verify')
        absurl = 'http://' + current_site + relativeLink + "?token=" + str(token)
        email_body = 'Hi ' + user.username + \
                     ' Use the link below to verify your email \n' + absurl
        data = {'email_body': email_body, 'to_email': user.email,
                'email_subject': 'Verify your email'}

        # Util.send_email(data)
        mail.send(
                    [user.email],
                    "abc@gmail.com",
                    subject='Account Verification',
                    message=email_body,
                    priority='now',
                )
        return Response(user_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

serializer.py

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=68, min_length=6, write_only=True)
    role = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)

    default_error_messages = {
        'username': 'The username should only contain alphanumeric characters'}

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'role']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email', '')
        username = attrs.get('username', '')
        role = attrs.get('role', '')

        if not username.isalnum():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                self.default_error_messages)
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

```
python 3.10
Django 3.2
```

Comment: maybe it writes data in different database - so you can't see changes in your database. Did you check what database you have in settings.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the database connections. I make sure that is not the problem in this case @furas